# Problems with editable-text and beforeUpdate hook (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, meteor, callback

folks.  I'm working on my first serious Meteor project, and I'm running into a bit of an issue.

I've got a small page here that contains a table of Categories, and I am using editable-text to allow for edit-in-place functionality for a couple of the fields.  Editing seems to work, but to handle some verification, I've written/attached a callback to handle the `beforeUpdate` callback on the `limit` field for my document.

The callback seems to be...well...called back, but it's not having the effect on my data that I believe it should have.  Basically, if a user types in a value of something like `43`, I want this callback to force the value to `43.00` (two decimal places mandatory).

This code segment contains the callback itself:

```
EditableText.registerCallbacks({

    // Callback for editing category limit/budget.
    budgetCurrency: function(doc) {
        // Variables based on editing.
        var oldVal = this.oldValue;
        var newVal = this.newValue;

        // Verification:
        if (isNaN(newVal)) {
            // Reject value if not a number, don't make change.
            oldVal;
        } else {
            newVal = Number(newVal);
            console.log(newVal.toFixed(2));
            return _.extend(doc, {limit: newVal.toFixed(2)});
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or not.  The value that is returned via `console.log()` is just as I would expect it to be, however the same value (in code) is not what ends up being stored in the updated document.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I could just be overlooking something as far as how `beforeUpdate` works (callback), for all I know.

Documentation for the package in question is located at: https://atmospherejs.com/babrahams/editable-text

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is as expected. Javascript Number cannot be stored directly into mongo. It has to be converted to either an int or a float/double. In your case, it is being converted to an int which does not have decimal points.

Here are your options:

1. Store the value as a String (and loose the ability to do mongo airthmatic operations such as inc etc.)
2. Store the value as two separate integers divided between dollar and cents for before and after decimal point.
3. Use float or double and loose accuracy (only use this if you are storing something approximate as this is not suitable for exact financial values)

Comment: I sorta understand what you mean.  If I'm going to need to do some aggregation with these values (summing up a bunch of purchases, for example, and finding a "percentage used" of a budget (this is extremely simple stuff), would you think that double/float would be okay for stuff that basic?  It's not like this is corporate data or anything.